# How to send json events to ES with Logstash Plugin for Amazon ES?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, codec

I am new to ES. Trying to send json events to ES with https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es
However, when I give below configuration it does not recognize any events?

```
   input {
        file {
            path => "C:/Program Files/logstash-2.3.1/transactions.log"
            start_position => beginning
            codec => "json_lines"
        }
    }
    filter {
       json {
            source => "message"
       }
    }
    
    output {
        amazon_es {
            hosts => ["endpoint"]
            region => "us-east-1"
            codec => json
            index => "production-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            
        }
    }
```

I am running it in debug mode but there is nothing in the log
Also do I need to create the index before I start sending the events from Logstash?

The below config works somehow, however it does not recognize any json fields

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/Program Files/logstash-2.3.1/transactions.log"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}

output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts => ["Endpoint"]
        region => "us-east-1"
        index => "production-logs-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Running it on Windows 7

Comment: whats in the log ?
Logstash is quite terrible at parsing file, you really need to filter/parse it correctly to dump to output, otherwise it will simply ignore them.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html
>By default, each event is assumed to be one line. If you would like to join multiple log lines into one event, you’ll want to use the multiline codec or filter.

make sure the log is 1 line, no line break, correctly formatted json, and logstash does not re-read the lines it has processed, so you need to make sure "new" lines are appended to the file.

Answer (score 0):

There may be several things at play here, including:

- Logstash thinks your file has already been processed.  start_position is only for files that haven't been seen before.  If you're testing, set sincedb_path to /dev/null, or manually manage your registry files.
- You're having mapping problems.  Elasticsearch will drop documents when the field mapping isn't correct (trying to insert a string into a numeric field, etc).  This should be shown in the elasticsearch logs, if you can get to them on AWS.
- debug is very verbose.  If you're really getting nothing, then you're not receiving any input.  See the first bullet item.
- adding a stdout{} output is a good idea until you get things working.  This will show you what logstash is sending to elasticsearch.